# Is it possible to fill template text fields in Google Slides, from a google sheet, when someone click a link to create a pdf of the slides?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Slide presentation with several text templates. I also have a master file, with text data. As an example, in the slide there is a template called  and similar in the master Google Sheets file. I want to share a link that is unique and never changed in an email, and is there a way that when someone click that link, the google slide updated all values and let the user download an updated PDF. Basically, if the  is changed, I update the sheets file, and the user will download a pfd with the correct adress?

I have tried to create the script for the Slides, but if the data is changed in sheets, I need to change in Slides as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to change text from a Slides Presentation and from a Spreadsheet.

Fist I create a simple slide with a marker.

[image]

Then a script that searches the presention for the marker and replaces the text from a spreadsheet.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let present = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
    let slides = present.getSlides();
    slides.forEach( slide => {
        let shapes = slide.getShapes();
        shapes.some( shape => {
          let range = shape.getText();
            if( range.find(/\{\{marker\}\}/)) {
              let spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your spreadsheet id here");
              let value = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1").getValue();
              range.replaceAllText("{{marker}}",value);
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

[image]

Then in my spreadsheet I create an installed onEdit to replace the text in the presentation if the value in cell A1 is changed.  Note this only will work the first time because the marker is replaced by the text.

```
function onEditPresentation(e) {
  try {
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
      if( e.range.getA1Notation() === "A1" ) {
        let present = SlidesApp.openById("1o6ml4KZ4crkaYw06LAouDidaCrwMHWkE36Iuo0A_3Mo");
        let slides = present.getSlides();
        slides.forEach( slide => {
            let shapes = slide.getShapes();
            shapes.some( shape => {
              let range = shape.getText();
                if( range.find(/\{\{marker\}\}/)) {
                  range.replaceAllText("{{marker}}",e.value);
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              }
            );
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("onEdit() "+err);
  }
}
```

[image]

References:

- [SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app)
- [Presentation.getSlides()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getSlides())
- [Slide.getShapes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getShapes())
- [Shape.getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getText())
- [TextRange.replaceAllText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#replaceAllText(String,String))